# Automatic restart of non responding program via CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a batch file that automatically restarts my application if it stops responding.

But I have a problem in the program. After successfully killing the non-responding task it fails to start it again. Where can the problem be?

I'm relatively inexperienced with batch files, so thank you for your help.

```
@echo off
:start
tasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" > D:\tasklist.txt
find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    timeout 10
    tasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" > D:\tasklist.txt
    find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
    if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
        taskkill /im "infinite_loop.exe" /f
        timeout 10
        tasklist > D:\tasklist.txt
        find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
        if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
            echo %errorlevel%
        )
    )
)
timeout 5
goto start
```

I'm using an infinite loop program for testing. The batch file and the program are stored in the same file, when I will be done, i will add redirecting to the folder with an .exe file and move batch file to the startup folder.

Comment: Please use the `search` facility to find entries on SO about `delayed expansion`. The problem is that `%errorlevel%` has no special status and is not exempt from the parsing rules. You could probably use `if [not] errorlevel n` in your code which will execute the `true` code if `errorlevel`, as set dynamically, is [not] `n` **or greater than ** `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. As Magoo pointed out, your errorlevel's are nested, and this will prevent parsing they're actual values. Secondly, while you do close the program, you do not start it again. Here is a way to go about both problems:

```
@echo off

:start 
timeout 5

tasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" > D:\tasklist.txt
find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
if "%errorlevel%" neq "0" goto :start
:: else
timeout 10

tasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" > D:\tasklist.txt
find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
if "%errorlevel%" neq "0" goto :start
:: else
taskkill /im "infinite_loop.exe" /f
timeout 10

tasklist > D:\tasklist.txt
find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
if "%errorlevel%" neq "1" goto :start
:: else
Echo %errorlevel%
start "" "infinite_loop.exe"

goto :start
```

Instead of checking if `%errorlevel%` is the value you want and progress, you can check if its *not* the value you want and in that case restart the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and adjustment, but unfortunately the program still does't turn on.
And i have guestion, why is there one more quation? start "" "infinite_loop.exe"

Comment: Hallelujah, the program is fully functional, i just added before last find, where im trying to start program "ttasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" > D:\tasklist.txt " and it's working! Thx much. :)

Comment: My pleasure, if you would kindly mark my answer as correct I would appreciate it. As for what the first quotation marks do, it specifies the title of the program when its run, only really used if you're running a console application.

Comment: @J.Chudej make sure you update the code from mine, I added `tasklist > D:\tasklist.txt` before `find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt` as per your original code (My bad)

Comment: yeah, i type it as a comment, that i added tasklist to file, ant it works. I just add exe. file directory and make log, that writes time, date and string to text file, when was program restarted. :)
thx for your help, your answer is marked as correct. :)

Comment: What should be tasklist.txt in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Monacraft's answer. It appears that it checks too many times. To me, your nested if structure is more clear.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:start
tasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" > D:\tasklist.txt
find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (
    timeout 10
    tasklist /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" > D:\tasklist.txt
    find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
    if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (
        taskkill /im "infinite_loop.exe" /f
        timeout 10
        tasklist > D:\tasklist.txt
        find /C "infinite_loop.exe"  D:\tasklist.txt
        if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 1 (
            echo !ERRORLEVEL!
            start "" "infinite_loop.exe"
        )
    )
)
timeout 5
goto start
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you haven't added the code to actually start the program. It should be added in the if-statement where you `echo !ERRORLEVEL!`

Comment: It's my bad, i have echo %errorlevel% for check instead start x. The reason is why this if-statement doesenť complete. :)

Comment: Ok, does this make it better? I added what the OP also omitted.